# Эмулятор вычислительной машины

Tags: ассемблер, архитектура

Мне нужно разработать эмулятор вычислительной машины в классической архитектуре Фон Неймана, которая реализует набор команд.

Команды для этой машины будут иметь вид:

```
ZZZ XXXXX YYYYY FFFFF
```

- `ZZZ` - это название команды (например, `MOV` - присваивает ячейки значение), всего будет поддерживаться 7 команд.
- `XXXXX`, `YYYYY`, `FFFFF` - числа в двоичной системе счисления. При этом, если число является адресом памяти, то оно состоит из 5 разрядов, а если это значение
  находящиеся по адресу, то оно состоит из 8 разрядов.

ЭВМ оснащена 64 ячейками памяти данных, из которых 32 ячейки отданы под память данных, 32 - под память для программы. Размер ячейки 8 бит.

С эмуляцией работы самой ЭВМ у меня проблем нет. **Но я не знаю, как посчитать превышает ли программа 32 ячейки?** В том смысле, что если программа, например, содержит команду 
"DIV 01001 11001 10101", то эта команда в памяти эмулируемой ЭВМ будет занимать 4 ячейки (по ячейки на каждый элемент команды), или она будет занимать( 3 ячейки и каждый элемент будет идти друг за другом и в итоге команда будет занимать 18 бит)? Следующая командf будет начинаться с нового бита, или с новой ячейки?

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как должны располагаться команды в памяти ЭВМ на архитектуре Фон Неймана?**

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt 22 вопроса, а принятых всего 5... Заставляет задуматься: а оно надо отвечать, стучать по клаве, терять время, нервы?

Comment: Делайте попроще. 

Пусть каждая команда занимает 4 ячейки (вопрос о битовой границе автоматически отпадает).

Адресную арифметику делайте просто "по модулю" 32. Т.е. вычисляете исполнительный адрес (используйте арифметику без знака) и берите младшие 5 бит ( mem[addr & 0x1f] ).


Только вот архитектура с раздельными пространствами команд и данных, насколько помню, называется *Гарвардской*, а не *фон Неймана*.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, сколько максимум бит надо, чтобы закодировать команды. ZZZ XXXXX YYYYY FFFFF - это 18 бит. Значит можно сделать в машине 18-битовые ячейки и такая команда будет занимать её одну :) . Если же команда может быть, допустим, ZZZ XXXXXXXX YYYYY FFFFFFFF, т.е. любой из трёх операндов независимо может быть либо 5 бит, либо 8, то во-первых, получается максимум 3 + 8 * 3 = 27 бит, а во-вторых, надо закодировать, длины операндов, т.к. в 18-ти и даже в 27-ми битах не будет информации о том, где надо брать адрес ячейки, где - 8-битное число. Другими словами, набор бит ZZZXXXXXYYYYYFFFFF000000000 - неотличим от ZZZ XXXXXYYY YYFFFFF0 00000000 (команды с тремя 8-битными операндами). Так что можно, например, к команде добавить суффикс, будет 6 бит ZZZxyf, например, MOV (допустим, будет обозначаться комбинацией трёх бит 000), XyF: MOV, X - 8-битное число, y - 5-битный номер ячейки, F - 8-битное число.

Эти битики запихнуть в ячейки для программы - уже просто. Например, ZZZxyz00 - в первую, X, Y, F - по-отдельности в три последующие. Можете заморочиться с упаковкой этих 21-30 бит в нецелое количество байтовых ячеек и с переменной длиной команд (MOVxyf может занимать всего 6 + 5*3 бит), но не рекомендую. Думаю, с упаковкой в нецелое количество ячеек даже реальные инженеры, если бы проектировали такую машину, не стали бы заморачиваться. Это усложнило бы адресацию и снизило возможности дальнейшего расширения